# Grunt and Stylus or RequireJS subtasks

Tags: requirejs, gruntjs, stylus

It seems to me that I've missed something. Is there any possibility to make subtasks for Stylus or RequireJS within Grunt? I mean something like that:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    stylus: {
      dev: {
        compile: {...}
      },
      prod: {
        compile: {...}
      }
    }
});
```

For me it doesn't work. However when I write:

```
...
  stylus: {
    compile: {...}
  }
...
```

it work fine, creates file and so on... So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grunt tasks run in the next format:

```
taskname: {
    subtaskname: {
        // options
    }
}
```

So in order to make it work, you don't need to put the `compile` object within your `dev` and `prod` subtasks.

```
stylus: {
    dev: {
        // options
    },

    prod: {
        // options
    }
}
```

Best regards.